# how to declare mvc nodejs model using oracledb like mongodb example? oracledb does not define Schema?

Tags: node.js, oracle, model-view-controller, model

`
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

```
const Course = new Schema({
 name: {type: String, MaxLength: 255},
 description: {type: String, MaxLength: 600}
})

module.exports=mongoose.model('Course',Course)
```

`